# Given $A_{m\times n}$ and $B_{n \times m} (m<n)$. prove that AB is not singular and BA is singular

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following question which I can't seem to wrap my head around. I don't see how we can determine the desired just from the given info.

> Given $A_{m\times n}$ and $B_{n \times m}$ $(m<n)$. prove that AB is not singular (for every A) and BA is singular

Thanks for the help.

EDIT: Question in another form (closer to original text):

> Given $A_{m\times n}$ and $B_{n \times m} (m<n)$.
>
> 1) Is AB Singular?
>
> 2) Is BA Singular?

My answers say that 1 is false and 2 is true.

Comment: Technically, it's possible for them both to be singular. For example, if A is a zero matrix. Perhaps the question is "Prove that IF AB is not singular then BA is singular."

Comment: @DavidButlerUofA: No, the question does not state that, but the question is that for -every- $A , B$ it happens, so you can't pick $A=0$

Comment: But that is just my point. It's not true for *every* A and B that AB is not singular and BA is, so you can't prove it true for every A and B. It is most definitely true that if $m<n$ then BA is singular, but is not true that AB is nonsingular for all possible A and B of the right sizes.

Comment: @DavidButlerUofA: Let me try rephrase, maybe I made a mistake translating the question: Given $A_{m\times n}$ and $B_{n \times m} (m<n)$.1) Is AB Singular?2) Is BA Singular? My answers say that 1 is false and 2 is true.

Comment: @Jason It is acceptable to *also* post the question in your native language. Most people here are at least bilingual anyway.

Comment: @Jason Your answers are correct. The matrix $BA$ is necessarily singular whilst $AB$ may or may not be.

Comment: @GitGud, Ok, so for $A=0$ it contridicts AB, how about BA then?

Comment: @Jason Can you maximize $\text{rank}(BA)$ and conclude?

Comment: @GitGud rank$(BA) \le n$? But $BA_{n \times n}$ so how does that help?

Comment: @Jason Yes, it doesn't work, so you need a better estimate. [Bonus](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/755047/matrices-rank-problem/755054#755054).

Comment: [Related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579450/if-ab-i-a-is-full-rank-but-not-square-matrix-shall-we-have-ba-i).

Comment: @GitGud, Thanks for the additional info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is $ m \times n $ for $ m < n $, then the columns of $A$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^m$ (or whatever the field is). Since there are more than $ m $ of them, they must be linearly dependent and so there are nontrivial solutions to $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$.

Multiplying by $B$ on the left of both sides of this equation gives $BA \mathbf{x} = B\mathbf{0}$ so $BA \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$ (albeit a different zero vector). Since $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$ had a nontrivial solution, so must $(BA)\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$ and hence $BA$ is singular.

It is possible that $AB$ is singular or non-singular. For example, if $A$ is a zero matrix then $AB$ is also a zero matrix (of a different size) and so must be singular. However, for example, if $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ then $AB = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $AB$ is nonsingular.

In general, if the columns of $B$ define combinations of the columns of $A$ that are independent, then $AB$ will be nonsingular.

Comment: Great answer, Thanks!